# getting error: initial value of reference to non-const must be an lvalue

Tags: c++

These are the prototypes for these functions.

This is member function:

```cpp
virtual void write(std::ostream& os) const;
```

This one is free function:

```cpp
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Text& text);
```

I implement both functions like this:

```cpp
void Text::write(std::ostream& os) const
{
    if (m_content != nullptr)
    {
        os << m_content;
    }
}
    
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Text& text)
{
    return text.write(os);
}
```

My problem is I am getting this error:

```
C++ initial value of reference to non-const must be an lvalue
```

and I'm sure I have done everything right.

Comment: Text::write should return `os`

Comment: Please, change `return text.write(os);` to `text.write(os); return os;`. Your, `Text::write()` returns `void` which hasn't a proper return type for your overloaded `operator<<()`.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed by [Scheff](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7478597/scheff) in [the comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66951414/getting-error-initial-value-of-reference-to-non-const-must-be-an-lvalue#comment118345169_66951414), you need to return `os` from `Text::write`:

```
   std::ostream& Text::write(std::ostream& os) const
   {
       if (m_content != nullptr)
       {
           os << m_content;
       }
       return os;
   }

   std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Text& text)
   {
       return text.write(os);
   }
```